# Magento2 CE Memory limit has been reached when saving product

Tags: magento2, memory

When changing settings in a product I get the message:

```
Memory limit has been reached magento-2
```

Why is that and what causes this? Is it a problem in the version 2.0.9 I have running? Or is it because of the php settings which are not suitable? 
How to solve this? Any hints?

Comment: Increase `memory_limit` in Apache `php.ini` & restart Apache. Then check again

Comment: The problem is that it is on a hosted environment. So unfortunately I can not edit php.ini and restart apache

Comment: Then you can ask host provider to change the settings.

Comment: `magento2\.htaccess` Update `php_value memory_limit 768M` & `php_value max_execution_time 18000`

Comment: this is already in the .htaccess but seems not to work. So I ask the provider to act on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing the **memory_limit** setting in the **php.ini** file (root folder of your project)

Answer (score 0):

The cause is because PHP has exhausted the maximum memory limit as set by the configuration value `memory_limit`.

Go to php.ini file, increase `memory_limit` and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your Magento root folder and

```
vendor/tubalmartin/cssmin/cssmin.php
```

In this file go to `__construct` method you will find `memory_limit` and you can change another php related settings from here.

But this is a core file and its not good to change the core file. Whenever you upgrade Magento the change will loose.

Comment: Had a look at that file but I think its better and more future proof to ask the service provider to raise their limits for this shop.